# Create Overstrike Effect In A Cell

Tags: excel, unicode

I have been asked if there is any way to get Excel to produce an overstrike effect in a cell.  My first attempt was the use the BACKSPACE character:

```
 ="A" & CHAR(8) & "B"
```

But the display does not seem to honor the BACKSPACE:

[image]

Is this a font problem?  Is there a unicode approach ?

I hate to tell the client to search for a custom font.

**EDIT#1:**

For example.  This code:

```
Sub XBar()
   ActiveCell.Font.Name = "Arial MS Unicode"
   ActiveCell.Value = "X" & ChrW(773)
End Sub
```

Visually produces:

[image]

but this is not a general solution.

Comment: Hmm, it might be a font issue. I used the same, Arial Unicode MS size 11, and and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdbak.jpg).  (What do you mean though by a "overstrike effect"?)

Comment: @BruceWayne I added a visual example..............but this only works because the overbar hangs to the **left**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

[image: Screenshot of solution]

If so, then select the character(s) you'd like to strikethrough, click the arrow icon in the font section (circled below) and tick the box next to strikethrough.

[image: Screenshot of font]

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Where-is-the-font-Strikethrough-option-e6df3b9d-cea6-4406-9271-5a5a52d66738) for more information.

Comment: I believe what he is looking for is a way to overlap two characters; by attempting to add the backspace character, he was trying to put `B` over the `A`. At least, this is what I find when I google search character overstrike.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've got my wires crossed then. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Me neither, I don't think many people have. I'd leave your answer up just so that others don't get confused by this as well.

Comment: It is possible to put one character on top of another but only in certain circumstances.

Comment: BTW you can do this in Word http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CombineCharacters.htm so you can get the appearance of superimposed characters in Excel by embedding a Word document in a sheet...but I'm not offering this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the character set by putting one character on top of another BUT you can only do this with a limited set of symbols. These are known at the "Combining Diacritical Marks" and usually live towards the end of the font set.

For a spreadsheet document, I wanted to put in 9 recurring (ie 9 with a dot above it). This does not exist as one character but can be made by combining two.

First of all put in the 9, then from the Combining Diacritical Marks, choose the . and one will go above the other. I actually had to do this in Word and then copy and paste the new characters back to Excel to make them work.

[image: Image showing Combining Diacritical Mark use in Excel]

Once in Excel, I used a look up to convert the digit 9 into the dotted digit 9 wherever I needed it.

Different fonts have different ranges of these characters. Arial Unicode MS has some unusual ones. You need to look at the fonts and choose the most appropriate for your needs.

However, on the whole, I don't think you can put a B on top of an A!

Comment: Thanks for the response